# Over 1,000 email messages to a device from AWS SNS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have created an `AWS Lambda` function with this code:

```
console.log('Loading function');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';

exports.handler = function(event, context) {  
    console.log("\n\nLoading handler\n\n");
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();

    sns.publish({
        Message: 'Test publish to SNS from Lambda',
        TopicArn: 'TOPIC_ARN'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('push sent');
        console.log(data);
        context.done(null, 'Function Finished!');  
    });
};
```

When it runs, this code suppose to publish a message to an `AWS SNS` topic. I've subscribed an email address to this topic to check it.

When I clicked on the "Save & Test" button, I've started being blown up with emails. I got over 1,000 emails from it, and it doesn't stop.

I've tried to delete the topic, the subscription, the function itself, but nothing works. I keep getting those emails.

Is there anything I can do to stop this email rain?

Comment: Is the function running over and over? Did you subscribe it to some sort of event or schedule? It sounds like you deleted all the resources so now you just need to wait until all the queued emails are delivered.

Comment: It suppose to run only one time on the triggered event and right now I've just tested it, so it is very weird. For now, it stopped.

Comment: I would try setting up everything again and using the "dry-run" setting to test the Lambda function without actually sending messages to the SNS topic. Then check your function's CloudWatch Logs to see if it runs more than once.

Comment: Did you perhaps also subscribe this Lambda function to the SNS topic that it is publishing to, creating a loop?